# How to have a WHERE clause check items in a list in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause

I have a database table in `postgresql` and some of the fields contain lists.

Here's an example of the result of a `select` query.

```
(2, u'osgb1000001786024039', 10053, 1, u'2001-11-07', [u'Land', u'Buildings'], ...)
```

You can see that the sixth field (which is called 'theme') has a list with a single item.

My question is how do I write a `WHERE` clause that checks against the items in that list?

I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM os_mm.topographicarea
WHERE 'Buildings' IN theme
```

Which gives:

> syntax error at or near "theme"
>   LINE 2: WHERE 'Land' IN theme

Clearly that doesn't work, so what command or syntax am I missing?

Comment: What is the exact type of theme? Is it `text[]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM os_mm.topographicarea
WHERE 'Buildings' = ANY (theme)
```

See also from the [postgresql documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-ANY-SOME).